# Converting a c# snippet to vb .net (re EventHandler)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, events

I've been out of the loop for a while and now doing some coding again.

I'm having trouble convert a particular c# snippet to vb .net. Any help would be appreciated:

```
public Form1()
{
    // Add a listener for usb events
    myUsbDevice.usbEvent += new usbDevice.usbEventsHandler(usbEvent_receiver);
}

private void usbEvent_receiver(object o, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do Stuff
}
```

Relevant bits are:

```
// usbDevice Class        
public delegate void usbEventsHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
public event usbEventsHandler usbEvent;
```

My conversion is this:

```
// usbDevice Class
Public Delegate Sub usbEventsHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
Public Event usbEvent As usbEventsHandler
```

& this this what doesn't work (obviously):

```
Private Sub Form1()
    myUsbDevice.usbEvent += New usbDevice.usbEventsHandler(AddressOf usbEvent_receiver)  // this doesn't work. Says to use RaiseEvent although I think it should just be an AddHandler
End Sub

Private Sub usbEvent_receiver(o As Object, e As EventArgs)
    // Do stuff
End Sub
```

I'm just not quite sure how to convert it.
Just using AddHandler doesn't seem to make sense and won't either:

```
AddHandler myUsbDevice.usbEvent, Sub usbEvent_receiver() // am missing 'o' object and 'e' eventargs + the whole usbDevice.usbEventsHandler bit is gone and I don't think/know whether that's right.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+=` in c# in this case is assigning an event handler.

To do this in VB it would look like:

```
AddHandler myUsbDevice.usbEvent, AddressOf usbEvent_receiver
```

The `o` of object and `e` of eventargs are passed without having to name them explicitly.

You have already set up the signature properly of `usbEvent_receiver`.  VB will do the rest to pass the parameters.